# How do I Call PropertyChanged if I have a Binding to the Current DataItem (Path=.)

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datacontext, inotifypropertychanged

In my XAML code, I have a binding to the current dataitem like this:

```
Background="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=kBackground}}"
```

My converter uses several properties of the dataitem to determine the background.  When any of those properties change, the background color could change.  I want to send a notification to the target so that the background will change appropriately.  My question is that I don't know how to send such a notification when the binding path is ".".

If my converter uses PropertyA and PropertyB, calling:

```
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("PropertyA"))
```

and/or

```
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("PropertyB"))
```

doesn't trigger the binding.  I tried calling this:

```
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("."))
```

but it didn't trigger the binding either.

How do I call PropertyChanged in such a way that my "Path=." bindings get notifications that they need to update?

*This may be a duplicate question, but I couldn't find one.  I don't know the terminology very well.*

Comment: with your binding you bind to the instance in which you defined the binding right? If so, your converter isn't called because the instance itself didn't change. only its properties..

Comment: If your converter only changes the color I think that better way is add style with DataTriggers

Comment: I agree with @hameleon86 that a converter would be better, but only if you're testing if PropertyA or PropertyB equals something, such as `if A = X or B = Y return Red`. If you're testing other logic, such as `if A > X or B < Y or A > B return Red`, then you'll need a converter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using an [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx) instead, and passing it the properties it needs

```
<Grid.Background>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyMultiValueConverter}">
        <Binding Path="PropertyA"/>
        <Binding Path="PropertyB"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</Grid.Background>
```

This should get re-evaluated anytime a PropertyChange notification is raised for either `PropertyA` or `PropertyB`

The alternative using your current binding syntax would be to raise a `PropertyChange` notification of your parent data item anytime `PropertyA` or `PropertyB` changes.

For example, assuming your current data item is `SomeObject`:

```
SomeObject.PropertyChanged += SomeObject_PropertyChanged;

...

void SomeObject_PropertyChanged(object src, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "PropertyA" || e.PropertyName == "PropertyB")
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged("SomeObject");
    }
}
```